# How to solve issue with mainthread

Tags: android, json, multithreading, network-connection

I try get JSON data from a php file

```
public void connect(){
    System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%1" );
    Thread t = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

    try {

        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%2" );
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 0);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        String urlString = "http://url";
        //prepare the HTTP GET call 
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlString);
        //get the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = httpClient.execute(httpget).getEntity();
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%3" );
        if (entity != null) {
            //get the response content as a string
            String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            //consume the entity
            entity.consumeContent();

            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed, shut down the connection manager to ensure immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

            //return the JSON response

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response); 
            JSONObject jb =(JSONObject) jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
            String name= jb.getString("name");
            String punkt = jb.getString("punktezahl");

             //String name = jsonarray.getString("name");
             System.out.println("HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE" + name);
             fuehrender.setText(name);
             punkte.setText(punkt);
               }



    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

};
t.start();
}
```

If I do like this I get the message that only the original Thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

So because of this error message I tried it like this:

```
public void connect(){
    System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%1" );
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

    try {

        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%2" );
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 0);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        String urlString = "http://url";
        //prepare the HTTP GET call 
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlString);
        //get the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = httpClient.execute(httpget).getEntity();
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%3" );
        if (entity != null) {
            //get the response content as a string
            String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            //consume the entity
            entity.consumeContent();

            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed, shut down the connection manager to ensure immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

            //return the JSON response

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response); 
            JSONObject jb =(JSONObject) jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
            String name= jb.getString("name");
            String punkt = jb.getString("punktezahl");

             //String name = jsonarray.getString("name");
             System.out.println("HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE" + name);
             fuehrender.setText(name);
             punkte.setText(punkt);
               }



    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

});

}
}
```

Now, I get the `NetworkOnMainThread` error message.. How to break through this doom loop?

Comment: place your try-catch block in AsyncTask.

Comment: short answer is : you can't do networking **and** ui on the same thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `runOnUiThread`. Remove it. It should be used only for updating ui not for http get request.

Using `AsyncTask` is a better option. Make the http get request in `doInBackground` and parse the response also. You can return the result in `doInbackground` which is a param to `onPostExecute`.

So you can update ui in `onPostExecute` which is invoked on the ui thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Example:

To invoke

```
new TheTask().execute(); // in ui thread
```

Make `AsyncTask` an inner class of activity

```
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params1) {
        String response = null; 
            try {
                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 0);
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
                String urlString = "http://url";
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlString);
                HttpEntity entity = httpClient.execute(httpget).getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
         JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result; 
         JSONObject jb =(JSONObject) jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
         String name= jb.getString("name");
         String punkt = jb.getString("punktezahl");
         fuehrender.setText(name);
         punkte.setText(punkt);
    }

}
```

Comment: @user896692 you need to use thread or AsyncTask. AsyncTask is easier.

Comment: Probably because you are calling `connect()` from `UI`. Call it from a background `Thread`. But I agree, [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is much easier

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful! But how can I access my TextView from onPostExecute?

Comment: @user896692 declare textview as a instance variable and initialize it in onCreate. Make AsyncTask an inner class of Activity.

Comment: If your AsyncTask is an inner class, you can reference the TextView in your onPostExecute() method.